# Unexpected Result with `-Xmax-classfile-name` Compiler Option

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use the Scala compiler flag, .

```
$cat build.sbt
name := "shorten_class_names"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

organization := "foo.bar.com"

version := "1"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-Xmax-classfile-name", "75")
```

And my only source file:

```
$cat src/main/scala/net/HundredXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.scala
package net

object HundredXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX {

       def f: String = "foo"

}
```

Then, I build and publish locally:

```
$sbt clean compile publish-local
published shorten_class_names_2.11 to /Users/kevin/.ivy2/local/foo.bar.com/shorten_class_names_2.11/1/jars/shorten_class_names_2.11.jar
```

But, then I look at the `HundredX...class`:

```
$unzip shorten_class_names_2.11.jar 
Archive:  shorten_class_names_2.11.jar
  inflating: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF    
   creating: net/
  inflating: net/HundredXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX$.class  
  inflating: net/HundredXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.class
```

Its length exceeds 75 characters:

```
scala> "HundredXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.class".size
res1: Int = 113
```

Its length has not been reduced to 75 characters. I had expected this result due to the `"-Xmax-classfile-name", "75"` Scala compiler option.

What happened?

Comment: I think the limit is meant to apply to names automatically generated by the compiler?

Comment: Under what circumstances do names get automatically generated by the compiler, Seth?

Comment: The big one is lambdas. If you look in the classes directory or JAR of pretty much any Scala program, you'll see a lot of classes named things like `InputBox$$anon$7$$anonfun$focusLost$1`.

Comment: Thanks, Seth. I should've checked the `scalac` output: `$scalac -X |  -Xmax-classfile-name <n>       Maximum filename length for generated classes`

Comment: oh, I wouldn't blame yourself there, “generated” is vague